# Wordpress multilingual site to work with other plugins

Tags: wordpress

I have a project in which the client needs the site to support 5 different languages. After some research on Google and here, it's clear the two ways to do it would be either using Multilingual plugins or Multi-site.

My question is, if I were to use the wordpress plugins such as [qTranslate](http://wordpress.org/plugins/qtranslate/), how would the other plugins work, i.e slideshows, testimonials etc. For example, most of the slideshow plugins comes with only a single title fields. In that sense, is using plugins for the translation still efficient keeping in mind that I am going to be using sidebars and other plugins which don't support multingual? Or using the Multi-site is the only option?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I am developing a multilingual site, and I am using [wpml.org](http://wpml.org) plugin, and it works awesome the flow is like this:

- you can publish translations for posts, pages, custom post types and taxonomies
- you can easily translate menus
- you can translate strings
- you can translate media captions, titles, and so on
- you can translate any plugin output in both admin and site

I strongly recommend it. Let me know if you need more details.